# How to implement Angular Drag and Drop list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to implement drag and drop list on my website. I have the list items in two txt files, e.g., the first one:

(one item per line) for example:
food
milk
oil

The second txt file is empty.

The lists should display items from txt files. If I move an item from list A to list B the item should disappear in the first txt file and appear in second one.

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
 
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

How to modify the above code? please help me

Comment: you can do it via angularjs with that code you've mentioned. I can not detect what is your problem, is that about text files? or about drag and drop?

Comment: my problem is with load files to list, and with implementation operations on files (remove line, add liine of text)

Comment: Please, show us some code to help you!

Comment: you have to change your point of view, instead of thinking about a text file, think about a database. then with a backend server which works with this database, you can send http requests to server asking for change in database.

Comment: yes, i agree with you but in work i have acces only to ftp server